# Sql Server - Ver a estrutura da View

Tags: sql, sql-server

Executei os seguintes comandos no banco Sql Server:

```
comando 1:
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'vendas'

resultado 1:
TABLE_CATALOG     TABLE_SCHEMA     TABLE_NAME      TABLE_TYPE    
----------------  ---------------  --------------  ------------- 
Empresa 1         dbo              vendas          VIEW

comando 2:
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'vendas'

resultado 2:
TABLE_CATALOG     TABLE_SCHEMA     TABLE_NAME      VIEW_DEFINITION     CHECK_OPTION     IS_UPDATABLE    
----------------  ---------------  --------------  ------------------  ---------------  --------------- 
Empresa 1         dbo              vendas          (null)              NONE             NO

comando 3:
SELECT definition FROM sys.objects O JOIN sys.sql_modules M ON M.object_id = O.object_id WHERE O.object_id = object_id( 'dbo.vendas') AND O.type = 'V'

resultado 3:
definition    
------------- 
(null)
```

Minhas dúvidas são

- A tabela é mesmo uma `view`, ou esta é apenas uma descrição para algum outro tipo de tabela `Material`
- Como pegar mais informações sobre esta tabela se ela for uma `view`, quais as tabelas que a constroi ?
- A falta de informação da definição poderia ser falta de privilégio do usuário, como descobrir isto ?

Editado:

A [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175081.aspx) da Microsoft mostra que a coluna `sys.sql_modules.definition` pode estar criptografada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A tabela é mesmo uma view, ou esta é apenas uma descrição para algum outro tipo de tabela Material

É uma *view* sim. Se é uma descrição, vai depender do seu conteúdo.

> Como pegar mais informações sobre esta tabela se ela for uma view, quais as tabelas que a constroi ?

Use o comando `sp_helptext vendas`.

> A falta de informação da definição poderia ser falta de privilégio do usuário, como descobrir isto ?

Executando o comando acima com um usuário sem permissão de acesso fará o SQL Server devolver uma mensagem de erro avisando dessa falta de permissão.

Comment: Executei a procedure mas o retorno foi `>[Error] Script lines: 1-1 There is no text for object 'vendas'.`

Comment: Pode ser varias coisas. [Veja a documentação aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms176112.aspx).

Comment: Pois é, pode ser uma definição criptografada: sys.sql_modules -  "definição - NULL = Criptografado", acho que vou ter que esperar o retorno do responsável pelo banco, obrigado pela ajuda.